# After updating only product price through Csv using Sku code, it changes quantity to 0 in magento 1.6.0

Tags: product, import, csv, magento-1.6

We have updated only the price using Magento CSV import functionality, but it automatically changes my product quantity as well.
Below is the CSV file format

[image]

Can anyone suggest why this is happening and recommend a solution?

Answer (score 0):

you can directly update your price using script just create 1 file in root directory , and run that file , just copy and past below code in your script.
in above csv $_data[0] means sku column and $_data[1] means price column in your csv , and change csv path. in above function , before you run above script just take backup of your database.

```
<?php
require_once 'app/Mage.php';
Mage::setIsDeveloperMode(true);
ini_set('display_errors', 1);
umask(0);
Mage::app('admin');
Mage::register('isSecureArea', 1);
Mage::app()->setCurrentStore(Mage_Core_Model_App::ADMIN_STORE_ID);set_time_limit(0);
ini_set('memory_limit','1024M');

function _getConnection($type = 'core_read'){
return Mage::getSingleton('core/resource')->getConnection($type);
}
function _getTableName($tableName){
return Mage::getSingleton('core/resource')->getTableName($tableName);
}function _getAttributeId($attribute_code = 'price'){
$connection = _getConnection('core_read');
$sql = "SELECT attribute_id FROM " . _getTableName('eav_attribute') . "
WHERE entity_type_id = ? AND attribute_code = ?";
$entity_type_id = _getEntityTypeId();
return $connection->fetchOne($sql, array($entity_type_id, $attribute_code));
}function _getEntityTypeId($entity_type_code = 'catalog_product'){
$connection = _getConnection('core_read');
$sql = "SELECT entity_type_id FROM " . _getTableName('eav_entity_type') . " WHERE entity_type_code = ?";
return $connection->fetchOne($sql, array($entity_type_code));
}function _getIdFromSku($sku){
$connection = _getConnection('core_read');
$sql = "SELECT entity_id FROM " . _getTableName('catalog_product_entity') . " WHERE sku = ?";
return $connection->fetchOne($sql, array($sku));}

function _checkIfSkuExists($sku){
$connection = _getConnection('core_read');
$sql = "SELECT COUNT(*) AS count_no FROM " . _getTableName('catalog_product_entity') . " WHERE sku = ?";
$count = $connection->fetchOne($sql, array($sku));
if($count > 0){
return true;
}else{
return false;
}
}

function _updatePrices($data){
$connection = _getConnection('core_write');
$sku = $data[0];
$newPrice = $data[1];
$productId = _getIdFromSku($sku);
$attributeId = _getAttributeId();

$sql = "UPDATE " . _getTableName('catalog_product_entity_decimal') . " cped SET cped.value = ? WHERE cped.attribute_id = ? AND cped.entity_id = ?";
$connection->query($sql, array($newPrice, $attributeId, $productId));
}

$csv = new Varien_File_Csv();
$data = $csv->getData('/path/to/skus_prices.csv'); //path to csv
array_shift($data);

$message = '';
$count = 1;
foreach($data as $_data){
if(_checkIfSkuExists($_data[0])){
try{
_updatePrices($_data);
$message .= $count . '> Success:: While Updating Price (' . $_data[1] . ') of Sku (' . $_data[0] . '). <br />';

}catch(Exception $e){
$message .= $count .'> Error:: While Upating Price (' . $_data[1] . ') of Sku (' . $_data[0] . ') => '.$e->getMessage().'<br />';
}
}else{
$message .= $count .'> Error:: Product with Sku (' . $_data[0] . ') doesn\'t exist.<br />';
}
$count++;
}
echo $message;

?>
```